# Give an example of failure of the continuity of outer Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

We know that Lebesgue Measure possesses the following continuity property:

If ${\{B_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}}$ is a descending collection of **measurable** sets and $m(B_1)<\infty$ , then
\begin{equation}
m\left( \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}B_k \right)=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}m(B_k)
\end{equation}
Now we allow the sets fail to be measurable.
We consider the following problem.

**Give an example** of a sequence of descending sets $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ and $m^*(E_1)< \infty$, such that
\begin{equation}
m^*\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i\right)<\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty}m^*(E_i)
\end{equation}

I think the Vitali sets will be useful, but I don't know how to construct the example.

Comment: I think this works: Let $P \subseteq [0,1]$ be a Vitali set, write ${\mathbb Q} \cap [0,1] = \{r_1, \, r_2, \, \ldots \},$ and let $E_n = \cup_{k=n}^{\infty} (P + r_k).$ Now fill in all the appropriate details. For example, all these sets are subsets of $[0,2],$ which has finite outer Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro emm... I don't know how to specify $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}m^*(E_n)$

Comment: The simplest approach, I think, is to only justify the minimum amount of preciseness to make the proof work. In this case, we know $\lambda^{*}(P) > 0$ (otherwise $P$ would be measurable), we know each $P + r_k$ has the same positive outer Lebesgue measure (by translation invariance), and hence we know for each positive integer $n$ that $\lambda^{*}(E_n) \geq \lambda^{*}(P + r_n) = \lambda^{*}(P) > 0$ (the first inequality is from monotonicity of outer Lebesgue measure). Therefore, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}m^*(E_n) \geq \lambda^{*}(P) > 0.$

Comment: By the way, I recommend that you now try to answer your own question (this is allowed here), including in your answer as many details as you can. This will give you practice in writing proofs and possibly some useful feedback, and also it will likely make this something you don't have to later re-study (since after you have done this, you will probably remember enough of the details to reconstruct it by yourself at a later time). It also will ensure that someone actually answers this question in the way intended here, which I'm not doing right now, leaving this to you for the reasons I gave.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks a lot! I will try to answer it later.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Sorry... I still have a problem. I am confused about $m^*(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}(P+r_k))$.

Comment: The intersection of all the $E_n$'s is the empty set (hence the outer measure you seek is the outer measure of the empty set), which follows from the fact that $P + r_i$ and $P + r_j$ have no elements in common when $i \neq j,$ which follows from the way Vitali sets are constructed by picking certain equivalence class representatives. For example, if $p$ and $q$ belong to $P$ and $p + r_i = q + r_j$ (this come from assuming $P + r_i = P + r_j$ as sets), then $p - q = r_j - r_i,$ so $p$ and $q$ differ by a rational number, so $p$ and $q$ belong to the same equivalence class, so $\ldots$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124461/discussion-between-kelvin-chung-and-dave-l-renfro).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dave L. pointed out in the comments, we can construct an example as follows:

First let $P\subset [0,1]$ be a [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set). Since such a set is not measurable, we have $m^*(P)>0.$ Let also $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]=\left\{r_1,r_2,\cdots\right\}$, and $E_k:=\cup_{n\geq k}(P+r_n)$ so each $E_k\subset[0,2]$ and therefore by the properties of outer Lebesgue measure, we have $m^*(E_k)<\infty$ where $m^*(F)$ denotes the outer measure of any set $F\subset \mathbb{R}$. Again, by the monotonicity and invariance by translation of the outer measure we have $0<m^*(P)=m^*(P+r_k)\leq m^*(\cup_{n\geq k}(P+r_n))=m^*(E_k)$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore $\lim_{k\to\infty}m^*(E_k)>0.$

On the other hand, we have, by a simple calculation, $\cap_{k\geq1}E_k=\emptyset$, therefore $m^*(\cap_{k\geq 1} E_k)=0$.

We conclude that $\lim_{k\to\infty}m^*(E_k)> m^*(\cap_{k\geq 1} E_k)$ and we are done.